# add year in select clause linq

Tags: c#, linq

```
 var query =
            from u in this.Manager.GroupRecipients
            join sz in this.Manager.Sub
            on u.OD_ID equals sz.OD_Id into grpjoin

            join z in this.Manager.Users
            on u.ID equals z.ID

            join m in this.Manager.Order_Details1
            on u.OD_ID equals m.OD_Id

            join o in this.Manager.Orders
            on m.OrderId equals o.OrderId

            join p in this.Manager.Products
            on m.ProductId equals p.ProductId
            from sz in grpjoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where u.CampaignGroupId == groupid
            select new DTO
            {
                FirstName = z.First_Name,
                LastName = z.Last_Name,
                Email = z.Email,
                ProductName = p.Name,
                PurchaseDate = (DateTime)o.OrderDate,
                ExpiredDate = //stuck


            };
```

I have this code and from the select clause, I can have a purchase date by using casting Datetime to the order date. However, I want to put expired date to be 1 year after purchasing. Is there any way to achieve the result? I was trying to put this code line

```
ExpiredDate = new DateTime(o.OrderDate).AddYears(1)
```

but an error saying that **cannot convert from 'System.DateTime?' to 'long'**

Comment: what is the type of ExpiredDate ?

Comment: its DateTime @Sajeetharan

Comment: @user2779065: Are you sure, I would expect it's type is `long`...

Comment: @CommuSoft yes, in DTO, i declared ExpiredDate to be DateTime type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ExpiredDate = o.OrderDate.AddYears(1)
```

The original o.OrderDate will not be changed by this call, [`AddYears`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.datetime.addyears(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a *new* DateTime.

Your error is the result of calling a constructor that supposedly takes another DateTime object when no such constructor exists. You don't need a constructor call though, so just omit it.

Comment: It returns an error 'System.Nullable<System.DateTime>' does not contain a definition for 'AddYears' and no extension method 'AddYears' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Nullable<System.DateTime>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: @user2779065 So you need a way around that. But my crystal ball is away for maintenance, so you will need to explain what you want. What *should* happen if the OrderDate is null?

Comment: I am trying to set the value of expireddate to be 1 year after the purchase date. Orderdate will never null. actually the value of the purchase date is in this format 2013-10-04T15:46:10. Im not sure if it is datetime format. Im still beginner in this field

Comment: Your LINQ statement says the OrderDate *can* be null. If you are *sure* (even if your database says otherwise!) then you could use `o.OrderDate.GetValueOrDefault().AddYears(1)`. But that's at your own risk. It would be better to fix your datasource if the constraints don't match.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is DateTime() expects a long where you have given a another DateTime object. Check the different constructors of DateTime.
You can simply say

```
ExpiredDate = o.OrderDate.AddYears(1);
```